# How can I install the latest Netbeans?

Tags: software-installation, netbeans

In Ubuntu Software Center the Netbeans version is netbeans `7.0.1+dfsg1-5ubuntu2`
but Netbeans 8.1 is available in the Netbeans website.

Answer (score 3):

Repository software will always tend to lag behind a little. Adding a PPA often fills the gap and there is a nice one for Netbeans:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vajdics/netbeans-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netbeans-installer
```

And on Trusty Tahr this successfully installs Netbeans version 8.1:

[image]